# Is there an elasticsearch equivalent to the Solr Terms Component?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I want to take a look at the actual terms in an Elasticsearch index. In Solr, I can just open the admin and get a list of the most common terms. Is there an Elasticsearch equivalent of this?

Comment: New in 8.6, there's the [`frequent_items` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-frequent-items-aggregation.html) that might be of help

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but I don't think that relates to what I'm trying to do. I'm just trying to dump the terms in the term dictionary, preferably in frequency order.